# Google Master Tool: How allow external links in robots.txt

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, google-maps

I have a problem with google rendering.

Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Because it's blocked by its own google `robots.txt` file.

Here's an example of an external link. `https://www.google.com/maps/vt?`

`https://www.google.com/robots.txt`

[image: Google robots.txt]

Can I allow this in my website using my own `robots.txt`? So I can avoid the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't control which URLs other websites ask bots to avoid.

Comment: From this blog. https://www.seroundtable.com/google-on-crawling-javascript-sites-progressive-web-apps-21737.html. It used to say "Ensure that all required resources (including JavaScript files / frameworks, server responses, 3rd-party APIs, etc) aren't blocked by robots.txt".

Comment: @JoseAlvinRañola — Yes, but that would be "the robots.txt for the site hosting the URL" not "your own robots.txt"

Comment: Do should I ignore the warnings in the google master tool? Crawl > Fetch as Google > Rendering.

Comment: If it's warning you something is blocked - then be aware Crawlers won't use that asset. If this is crucial to rendering your page then it needs to be unblocked. Look at the render, make sure that all your content is intact, then you can ignore it.